# joomla в глазах нуба

Tags: joomla

Залил и установил шаблон joomla 1.7. На сайте отображается не тот шаблон который я видел при скачивании, а отображается практически пустая страница.

Залил другой шаблон и с ним тоже самое. Мне объяснили, что это нормально и так будет с каждым шаблоном. Сказали, что нужно разбираться с модулями.

Объясните поподробней, что нужно сделать для корректного отображения шаблона?

Comment: а как создать модули ? и где их создавать ?

Comment: и еще вопрос куда делись все меню, шапка сайта,  блоки и т.д которые я видел в скрине шаблона при скачивании ?

Answer (score 1):

шаблон содержит в себе скилет вёрстки и стили для модулей и компонентов, поэтому если вы поставили шаблон, но не создали модули и не наполнили сайт контентом, то шаблону попросту не к чему применять эти стили

Comment: Вполне логично!

Answer (score 0):

Как правило, когда скачиваешь шаблон, с ним идет архив быстрой развертки, то есть архив с джумлой где уже установен шаблон и модули.

При установке такого архива, необходимо будет установить демо данные.